# How to trigger code on "Product add event" in Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am trying to save product id, only when new product is added in Prestashop.

I am not sure which hook to use ?

I am using `prestashop 1.7.4.4` version & `actionObjectProductUpdateAfter` hook but it saves product id multiple times whenever I save product.

Any thoughts on this please ?

Answer (score 0):

you have the dedicated **hookActionProductAdd** for that event.

Comment: can i use "hookActionObjectProductAddAfter" ?

Comment: sample code of what ? you can read here how hooks work => https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/